# Does Android clean app cache on update?

Tags: android, caching

In this [document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files), Google says that:

> When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's
>   files from internal storage.

But does it clear app cache (or any other data inside internal storage) automatically when update app version (for example from v1.0 to v1.1)?

Because when I'm monitoring my company's app, the `/cache` folder goes down trend each time we release and users update to new app version.

I did a test on my phones and see that the app cache did decrease size. But I'm not sure all devices also be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Internal storage**:

When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your app's files from internal storage.

**External storage**:

- Public files: Files that should be freely available to other apps and to the user. When the user uninstalls your app, these files should remain available to the user.
- Private files: Files that created using `getExternalFilesDir()` and rightfully belong to your app and will be deleted when the user uninstalls your app.

Yes, it clean data when user uninstalls, but **NOT when user updates your app**.

Note that some app does implement it's own cleaning mechanism by:

- Catching `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED` using `BroadcastReceiver`, then trigger clean some specific data.
- Run a cron job to clean data after a time interval or when size of a folder reaches it's threshold/upper limit.

For detailed information, see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage).

Comment: After checking I finally found out that this app clear cache after reaching 100 MB. So may be your answer is right.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Uninstall will only remove internal files bundled with the
>   application, folders create in the external storage will not be
>   deleted when uninstall. for database, the database will be deleted
>   when uninstall but will remain for updated application.
>
> Still on the database, its depends on the way the developer built the
>   application, if there is a change of database version, there can be a
>   replace or a complete removal of the database.

Also I'm adding a link that I hope will help you;
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Good Luck, G.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I think other directory will not be remove, but I'm not sure about app cache. Because I did some tests on my phone and it decrease size.