# Using serializible to safe data from Android App

Tags: android

when I use serializible to store data from an Android app in the internal storage, is there a danger of losing data, or does the data remain safed, even after an update?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Android clean app cache on update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148717/does-android-clean-app-cache-on-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App data remains after an app update or a system update. It does not survive the app being uninstalled and reinstalled. However, app data back up might be what you are looking for. Consult the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup) for more info.

If you are serializing your own classes, and the classes might change as your app is updated, there are additional issues (independent of Android) that you need to consider. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678136/managing-several-versions-of-serialized-java-objects).